# How to use breadcrumbs in Joomla in custom components?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, breadcrumbs

I wrote simple component by this example, but when i entering it i see Home instead of my components name.

And also is it possible to get deeper, for example joomla->my_component->some_other_component, but exactly after mine.

P.S.

Found http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_breadcrumbs, but how use it automatically in every view?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
$pathway =& $mainframe->getPathway();
$breadcrumb = $pathway->setPathway(array());
$pathway->addItem( JText::_( 'YOUR_BREDCRUMB_ITEM' ),'');
```

Replace `YOUR_BREDCRUMB_ITEM` with your item name. Hope this will help.

Comment: Please use the `code block` in the editor to highlight code segments.